# How to scrape multiple tables with same name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a site where the table classes have the same name.

There are 3 types of tables and I want to get the headers just once then get all the information from all three tables into a xlsx file.
Website = https://wiki.warthunder.com/List_of_vehicle_battle_ratings

running the code with `vehical = soup.find('table')` works. But I only get the first tables information.
I've tried changing it into `vehical = soup.find_all('table')`

But that gives me this error.

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Here is my full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def updatebr():
    url='https://wiki.warthunder.com/List_of_vehicle_battle_ratings'
    headers =[]
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    vehical = soup.find('table')
    

    for i in vehical.find_all('th'):
        title = i.text
        headers.append(title)

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)

    for row in vehical.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        data = row.find_all('td')
        row_data = [td.text for td in data]
        length = len(df)
        df.loc[length] = row_data


    df.to_excel('brlist.xlsx')
```

Full Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\WT\BRtest.py", line 35, in <module>
    updatebr()
  File "c:\Python\WT\BRtest.py", line 24, in updatebr
    test = vehical.find_all('tr')
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2289, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it more simple, since you already involve `pandas` - This wil [`pd.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) all tables in a list an [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them to a single one:

```
pd.concat(
    pd.read_html(
        'https://wiki.warthunder.com/List_of_vehicle_battle_ratings',
        attrs={'class':'wikitable'}
    ),
    ignore_index=True
).to_excel('brlist.xlsx')
```

|  | country | type | name | ab | rb | sb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Italy | Utility helicopter | A.109EOA-2 | 8.7 | 9 | 9.3 |
| 1 | Italy | Attack helicopter | A-129 International (p) | 9.7 | 10 | 9.7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1945 | USSR | Frigate | Rosomacha | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 1946 | USSR | Motor gun boat | Ya-5M | 1.3 | 1.3 | 1.3 |

---

However to answer your question - Since using `vehical = soup.find_all('table')` you have to performe an additional loop iterating the `ResultSet`. Used [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) here to simplify.

```
...
url='https://wiki.warthunder.com/List_of_vehicle_battle_ratings'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
vehical = soup.select('table.wikitable')

pd.DataFrame(
    [list(row.stripped_strings)
     for t in vehical 
     for row in t.select('tr:has(td)')
    ],
    columns=list(soup.table.tr.stripped_strings)
).to_excel('brlist.xlsx')
```

Comment: Did not know I could do that. Thank you kindly!